# Lime Model Explainer in Python vs R

Tags: python, r, model, h2o, lime

I am trying to convert some R code to Python. The code builds h2o models and uses Lime for explanations. The Lime modules in each language seem to be quite different.

What would be the equiavlent python functions to this R code?

```
explainer <- lime(x=observations, model=mymodel)
explainations <- lime::exaplin(x=observations, explainer=explainer,n_permutations=5000, feature_select="highest_weights", n_labels=5, n_features=10)
```

This is a multiclass classification problem with 3 classes. I was thinking the best translation in Python would be to use the LimeTabularExplainer.

```
explainer = lime.lime_tabular.LimeTabularExplainer(observations, mode='classification', class_names=myclasses,feature_names=observationCols)
explainations = explainer.explain_instance(observations, mymodel, num_samples=5000, num_features=8)
```

This doesn't seem to be working through so I am not confident. Is there a better way to translate this R code, or better Lime documentation somewhere for explaining models.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the H2O Explainability module.  We don't have LIME, but we have SHAP.  https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/explain.html

Comment: There's also this reference for using H2O in the lime Python package: https://marcotcr.github.io/lime/tutorials/Tutorial_H2O_continuous_and_cat.html